# How to group RSS in threads?

Tags: rss, jira, thunderbird-addon

How to group RSS messages in Thunderbird in threads based on Jira issue id?

Jira's RSS feed "Activity Stream" reports every single activity on issue. In thunderbird i want to group updates based on jira IssueID and display it in threads.

How to create addon that can make it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Thunderbird supports ATOM Threading Extensions.
But JIRA's RSS does not include them. Open a FeatureRequest @Jira.

Another way would be to do it on the client(thunderbird) side via naming conventions (RE: IDENTIFIER) but no idea if there's a plugin already offering that.